# A uniformizer of a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, say $[L:\mathbb{Q}_p]=n$. The uniformizer of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $p$, let we assume that $\sqrt[n]{p} \notin L$ and consider $K=L(\sqrt[n]{p})$. Is $\pi_L\cdot \sqrt[n]{p}$ the uniformizer of $K$ where $\pi_L$ is the uniformizer of $L$?

Comment: No. What is an uniformizer again?

Comment: This is a generator of the maximal ideal of the ring of integers of $K$.

Comment: Ok, but concretely $O_K$ is the subring of elements with non-negative valuation and an uniformizer is any element of $K$ with minimal strictly positive valuation. $v(\pi_L)$ is $>0$ and smaller than $v(\pi_L p^{1/n}) = v(\pi_L)+\frac1n v(p)$ so automatically $\pi_L p^{1/n}$ isn't an uniformizer.